# Cannot calculate memory: insufficient memory remaining for heap

Tags: ibm-cloud, monitoring

I pushed an [app](https://github.com/watsonwork/watsonwork-java-starter) from GitHub to Bluemix after I created an Availability Monitoring Service instance. I see the following error message:

> APP/0Cannot calculate memory: insufficient memory remaining for heap.
>   Memory limit 512M < allocated memory 603532K
>   (-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M,
>   -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=35839K, -XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize=4492K, -Xss1M * 300 threads)

There seems to be enough memory available (1.250 GB/8 GB Used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Availability Monitoring does not instrument the application in any fashion, but merely monitors it externally (by making GET requests).  This looks to be an issue with the APP itself.

Answer (score 0):

opened an issue, resulting in a change: https://github.com/watsonwork/watsonwork-java-starter/commit/8b6c0abd8e8052f154cc703cdceb77f00d558404